# Phonegap issue navigator undefined

Tags: cordova

Hello guys i createing my first phonegap app. installed the plugins and everything , attached the cordova.js to my html but its not loading the api
i keep getting 
cannot call method 'alert' of undefined

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        showAlert();
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }
```

Comment: which version of cordova and which plugin you have installed for notification ?

Comment: lastest phonegap 2.9 and latest cordova.js from cordova 3.3 i think.
about plugins i think i just did phonegap plugin add git . something like that. and then build it again using phonegap build android

Comment: Ur jar file points to 2.9 and ur cordova.js is from 3.3 which is the issue... Create a project using latest version which has all the files of same version

Comment: Wait wait. should i run BUILD everytime i update the www folder?

Comment: You should definetely have to read all the documentation mate, you are going to waste more time just jumping into the water... http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

Comment: Did you configure your config.xml file? see my answer below - please up vote if it helps

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in Android, make sure you have included the cordova.js before the above script.

Better documentation can be found here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

Comment: i do include the cordova.js file :/

Comment: include at first of all tag script

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cordova with phonegap? If you are using phonegap build stick with phonegap if no just use cordova. Do not mix them... and always read all the doc. Use the CLI to create the project, add platforms, add plugins and build project.
Be sure to run the command at the project root folder.
I suggest start a new project and copy paste your code.

Comment: i downloaded phonegap package 2.9 , but where is the cordova.js file (or phonegap.js) file , the file i need to include

Comment: ok now i was using that file of cordova from phonegap 2.9 package 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipes\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\assets\www\cordova.js 
i was assigning it to my js\ folder on my www\ folder.
and the file is above on top after the jquery.js file and still same ERROR

Comment: It is hard to undestand you, as I told you start a brand new project just using CORDOVA. On the other hand, did you bother adding the notification plugin? "cordova plugin add" http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

Comment: ok , the issue was that i did not BUILD a new package after i update my www folder.
It was not in the code that i need to rebuild it after each update on my www folder. since i was testing it using eclipse i got confused

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me in android was to run:

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Cordova 3.0 now requires that you add plugins for each functionality that you are going to use.

But even before the plugins, you need to make sure your config.xml file is configured properly.

1) Configure your config.xml for the device (iOS, Blackberry, etc.)

See here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#iOS%20Configuration

2) Add plugins

For the notification: run at command prompt "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs"

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/7/19/PhoneGap-30-Released--Things-You-Should-Know

If you installed the plugins and its not working, you probably didn't configure your config.xml file yet.